# Python pandas groupby agg: sum one column while getting the mean of all the rest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to group my fields based on date, and **get a mean of all the columns, except a binary column which I want to sum** in order to get a count.

I know I can do this (manually) by:

`newdf=df.groupby('date').agg({'var_a': 'mean', 'var_b': 'mean', 'var_c': 'mean', 'binary_var':'sum'})`

But there are about 50 columns (other than 'binary_var') that I want to mean, and I feel there must be a simple, quicker way of doing this instead of writing each `'column title' :'mean'` for all of them. I've tried to make a list of column names but when I put this in the `agg` function, it says a list is an unhashable type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','a','b','b','b','b'], 'b':[10,20,30,40,20,10], 'c':[1,1,0,0,0,1]}, 'd':[20,30,10,15,34,10])
df 
   a   b  c   d
0  a  10  1  20
1  a  20  1  30
2  b  30  0  10
3  b  40  0  15
4  b  20  0  34
5  b  10  1  10
```

Assuming `c` is the binary variable column. Then,

```
cols = [ val for val in df.columns if val != 'c']
temp = pd.concat([df.groupby(['a'])[cols].mean(), df.groupby(['a'])['c'].sum()], axis=1).reset_index()
temp 
   a     b      d  c
0  a  15.0  25.00  2
1  b  25.0  17.25  1
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would build the agg dict automatically:

```
sum_cols = ['binary_val']
agg_dict = {col: 'sum' if col in sum_cols else 'mean'
               for col in df.columns if col != 'date'}

df.groupby('date').agg(agg_dict)
```

Comment: Hi- thank you! This makes sense to be, but unfortunately it raised a data error- `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Comment: So print out agg_dict and debug it. This looks cleaner than the other approach.